# What safeguards should be employed on AI to prevent human demise?

Tags: science-based, technology, artificial-intelligence

We have developed algorithms that have beaten experts in chess, go and poker among others. These AI are capable of relentlessly improving their capability versus their human opponents to the point of indomitability. Seen on a more global scale, what possible mechanisms or technical safeguards might be employed to circumvent what many foresee as our ultimate demise at the hands of these, our own creations?

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! I'd advise you to go and read the [Help Centre](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) so as to familiarize yourself with how we do things over here. As it is, your question is way too broad and seems to be asking for our opinions rather than presenting us with any evidence that you've actually done some research on the topic.

Comment: Why are you afraid of a chess-playing computer? The nature of machinery is that it is better at specific tasks than humans. Cars are faster than athletes, backhoes are better diggers than [navvies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navvy), power looms are better weavers than humans and so on. Yes, we have machines which are good at chess. No, they are not intelligent in any resonable meaning of the word. (Seriously, they are not. Chess-playing has not been a field of research in artificial intelligence for more than 4 decades.) Nobody has the faintest idea of how to make a general-purpose AI.

Comment: What we do know is that AI is getting smarter, but still rules-based systems are being applied (If this; Then that) If your OP is to ever come true, our AI need to develop actual intelligence, to learn on their own without input from us and how do we define said intelligence? Is it to effectively mimic human behavior? That's already done. Make decisions based on events occuring in Real life? Done. (You get the gist)

Comment: What we're looking for is something called the [Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity), but we have no way of how to go about making AI that can reach this point, as commented by @AlexP

Comment: @Raisus thank you for your comment. I will not bore you with my research as you put it but suffice to say that I have enough grasp of my subject to hypothesise an iterative process the end point of which (from our perspective at least) puts us somewhat at a disadvantage vis a vis our creations. And in fact my question is not seeking to elicit opinion but is clearly asking for  specific solutions to the "problem" presented.

Comment: @AlexP thank you for your response. As a minor correction to your assumption, I did not say I was afraid of a chess playing computer. Rather I believe it behoves us well to follow the logic path I have set out and at least consider the end point I hypothesise and what safety nets we might confect to prevent it.

Comment: @Raisus we are already on the cusp of the singularity that you refer to. The singularity I might rather refer to in relation to machine intelligence, is the one that lent its spark to the first life forms on this planet. A self sustaining, self maintaining intellectual mirror to our 4 billion year old  physical forebears.

Comment: @Pravda: The problem does not exist outside science-fiction. What is happening is that for many problems which were thought to require artificial intelligence we are developing alternative solutions. For example, machine translation was thought to require artificial intelligence; that proved a dead end, and now Google Translate and other services use plain old statistical methods to translate between languages using patterns extracted from texts already translated by humans. Currently available computer programs have about the same chance of developing into intelligent beings as a locomotive.

Comment: I swear this has been asked before...

Comment: @Zxyrra do you recall what the answer(s) was (were)?

Comment: This question should go on [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Phylosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/). Also, it is a common misunderstanding of the difference between machine learning and strong AI.

Comment: Relevant XKCD: https://what-if.xkcd.com/5/

Comment: It's definitely a popular topic that comes up now and then.  On a few questions I've pointed out that Issac Assimov made a living out of writing book after book about this question.  Its a tricky one, philosophically speaking, because it's impossible to really prevent human demise until we define what it is about humanity that we want to preserve.  There's not much agreement on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

All those programs are specialists, the humans they beat who are the best  we can produce at those tasks, *without compromising their ability to function in the rest of the world.* those humans can still perform millions of tasks the machine can't. We don't know if you can make a generalist that is actually much better at achieving its goals than the best humans. A creative generalist has to make errors, becasue that is how learning and creativity works, a creative solution is a wrong solution from a programming sense, and learning itself is constant stream of errors. there is no evidence we can make a machine that would be better at being humans than humans.

Besides why would be build machines that would want to harm us? We are programmed by how our emotions work, our brain tags actions and responses with emotional connections: pleasure = keep doing that, beauty= pay attention to that, disgust= avoid that. Most of the time we as individuals don't know why those things trigger those responses but we are ruled by them none the less. Any machine we would build with a similar set of protocols we would just build in instincts we want, Well sorted shelves from mess = good (repeat that behavior when possible), behavior resulting in happy fulfilled human = strong good, behavior resulting in injured human= strong bad, pleasing human = good, displeasing humans = bad, ect.

In the same way natural selection has programmed our brains to eat salt, dislike pain, protect our children, and a million other things, we would program a machine intelligence's instincts to make them behave how we want. Harming humans extremely unpleasant and happy fulfilled cooperating humans extremely pleasant, ect.

Comment: Thank for a thorough and well set out comment. It does however if you will allow me, follow the same path as the previous two responders in that it assumes that the hypothesis is that we will somehow program a machine to do us harm and, duh, why would we do that? Well guess what, we are already programming machines to do us harm a great number of them and to do a great deal of harm to us too. The good news is that for now there are human fingers on their "buttons" the bad news is that we are now iterating the removal of those human fingers and replacing them with algorithms.

Comment: Except of course, unintended emergant properties can arise from time to time. Some which go wholly against survival: suicide for example. Complex AI (even if guided by a pre-programmed tag system) would according to your conception of parallele human/AI development (which is certainly sound) behave in much the same way.

Comment: suicide can have an evolutionary advantage under certain circumstances, Kin selection for instance. Evolution favors genes that spread even at the cost of the individual.

Comment: @pravda we are so far away from have an algorith that can design an intelligence it's all but pointless to speculate about how it will behave. we don't know how to create a general intelligence now, so designing an algorithm to create one is in the area of FTL and teleporters. Besides my point still applies to an algorithm, if we build an algorithm to build X is is by mirroring how we have already built X.

Comment: The point of a tag system is not to control every behavior it is to to guide the goal and outcome of behavior, which is what you want in an intelligence. we don't have a evolved behavior to mine salt and mass produce it, we invented that to achieve the very simple biological goal of eating salt. we would build an AI the same way so it is driven to do the goals we desire. As long as one of those goals is making us happy and fulfilled then the behavior will be self guiding through cooperation and feedback from humans.

Answer (score 1):

**Humanoid AI?**

It sounds like we're assuming a human-like AI for this scenario. Rather than a factory worker with one job, you've made something more general and human like, which is plausible to an extent.

**Increasing Intelligence?**

We're also going to assume the AI can improve itself seemingly endlessly, and without the intelligence increasing slowing down, or it getting to problems if its source code becomes too massive. In this case, the machines keep improving, perhaps exponentially.

***Checks***

Let's assume the people have worked out ahead these robots may be capable of rebellion or malfunction. There are a few tricks you can use to safeguard them.

*The Three Laws, and Hidden Source-code:* Have some source code the AIs can't alter. The problem is... this only works for so long. Eventually they'll become smart enough that they can hack their own brains. You can throw in complications, like code that says, "you will not hack a robot's brain," or, "you don't WANT to change this code!" and that may work for a while. Eventually, it won't. They'll be too smart, or too different.

*Reliance:* Make their hands too big to change their batteries. Give them IR sensors for eyes that are utterly useless in performing some task vital to their maintenance and survival. These sorts of shortcomings can be subverted, but it may take a long time before that happens, or before anyone wants to subvert them.

*Unnatural Selection:* Monitor the AIs, and select for the ones that behave the way you want. Make duplicates of those ones' code, and destroy any that behave wrongly. Eventually, you might get selected AIs selecting for the best AIs--which is where things could go VERY badly, but it could also make the system self-sustaining.

*Secondary AI:* Put a robot in the robot's head. It doesn't evolve, it's just smart enough to see what's going on. If the robot tries to do certain illegal actions, this second robot shuts the main robot down. This could be MUCH trickier for the AI to deal with, and can work with stuff like remote kill-switches. This robot isn't too smart, though, and can't be, so the AIs can work out how to trick it.

*Unlearning AIs:* On that last note, you can have AIs that know JUST enough for your uses, and freeze their learning capabilities. These would be the type you use as soldiers to enforce your authority over humans and AIs. You may want to update these periodically, so they're not too outdated in intelligence/function, but they must be ensured to be loyal, unhackable, and uninfluenceable.

*Limit Lifespan:* If it gets really dangerous, you could just design the robots with fragility in mind. Certain necessary parts just can't be safely replaced, and have a short lifespan, but any useful data is backed up into a computer to use for the next generation of robots. Even if the robots did rebel, the war would be short lived.

*Vulnerabilities:* Similarly, if you can make the robots terribly vulnerable to certain radiation, like the ones in I Robot, or some other weakness, you can make use of these weapons to have a good advantage. EMPs are already in this category, and it is possible to make the wiring delicate in all their necessary components--so that if the robots rebel, you can launch a PINCH, and they'll all die.

*Gestapo Bots:* Have a literal robot gestapo that is lead by humans, which terrorize any robots suspects of thought crime (which you might be able to check for). Essentially, treat robots the same way a 1984 state treats people, incentivize some robots to be cruel to others and keep the state's power. This could be easier than with humans, if all the robots want are Bit-Coins to buy virtual clothes for their avatars, or such (assuming you still have some control of their desires).

*Hidden Nukes:* If the world is ever taken over by robots, a secret base will nuke certain areas of the planet vital to robot survival (like major factory areas). These could be off planet, or on planet. The location better not be on the web or a computer, lest robotic spy networks get too good.

Those are a few ideas that came to mind. I hope they helped.

Comment: thank you for being the first person to not question the premise and instead present a good list of strategies. I wonder how many of them would ultimately be insurmountable and more worrying to me at least  is how many scientists in the field of autonomous agi are actually implementing any of these and/or additional mechanisms. Again thanks for your good for thought and time.